# How to write a C function to detect cycles in a void* array

Tags: c, pointers, cycle

I'm trying to implement the C function `int contains_cycle(void *const array[], size_t length)` to detect if there are any "cycles" in an array of void pointers. All elements of this array either point to an adress of this array or to NULL. Pointers still quite overwhelm me and I've got no idea where to start.

Just to clarify, what I mean by cycle, here are some examples. Just for illustration the first element's adress is always at adress 0x1 and pointers have the size of 1 byte.

`{NULL, 0x3, 0x2}` -> should return 1, cycle between `array[1]` and `array [2]`

`{0x2, 0x3, 0x1}` -> should return 1, cycle between all the elements

`{0x2, 0x3, NULL}` -> should return 0, no cycle

I would appreciate any help and if my goal is still not quite clear, I am happy to explain more.

My idea would be iterating over the array and somehowe "follow" the pointers to see if I end up on the starting point again. If that's the case for at least one element, I've found a cycle.

Comment: There are well known algorithms for loop detection in linked lists. Your array *is* a linked list for that purpose.

Comment: As outlined, if you ignore NULL, does any non-increasing list form a cycle?  If so then you can start with the 2nd element and compare the current and last element to see if it's increasing.

Comment: google "hare and tortoise algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just "follow the pointers", but you need to know whether you followed to a pointer that you already hit.
So my idea to solve your problem is to make a struct that contains an index instead of a pointer because this makes life so much easier...

```c
typedef struct {
    size_t toIndex;
    bool marked;
} Entry;
```

Then I create a new array of all these entries with the same length as the original. I calculate the toIndex that I store in the struct using the current element's pointer minus the address of the array's beginning.

```c
bool contains_cycle(void* array[], size_t length) {
    Entry newArray[length];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        size_t toIndex = ((size_t) array[i] - (size_t) &array[0] ) / sizeof *array;
        newArray[i] = (Entry) { toIndex, false };
    }
```

After that I look for the first index where the pointer is not null

```c
    size_t index = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == NULL) continue;
        index = i;
        break;
    }
```

Now, if we just let a loop run until we hit some index that is out of bounds (this will implicitly detect if we hit a NULL-element) and check if the current element is already marked. if so, return true.

```c
    while(index < length) {
        if (newArray[index].marked) return true;
        newArray[index].marked = true;
        index = newArray[index].toIndex;
    }
```

If the loop exits without a return you know that the loop did not start from there. You now need to check if the loop started from any other index that you haven't marked yet. But I'm too lazy to implement that now. Go try this yourself :)
For now I just return false

```c
    return false;
}
```

I tried to replicate your examples in the main function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t toIndex;
    bool marked;
} Entry;

bool contains_cycle(void* array[], size_t length) {
    Entry newArray[length];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        size_t toIndex = ((size_t) array[i] - (size_t) &array[0] ) / sizeof *array;
        newArray[i] = (Entry) { toIndex, false };
    }

    size_t index = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == NULL) continue;
        index = i;
        break;
    }
    while(index < length) {
        if (newArray[index].marked) return true;
        newArray[index].marked = true;
        index = newArray[index].toIndex;
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    void* example1[3];
    void* example2[3];
    void* example3[3];

    example1[0] = NULL;
    example1[1] = &example1[2];
    example1[2] = &example1[1];

    example2[0] = &example2[1];
    example2[1] = &example2[2];
    example2[2] = &example2[0];

    example3[0] = &example3[1];
    example3[1] = &example3[2];
    example3[2] = NULL;

    printf("%d ", contains_cycle(example1, 3));
    printf("%d ", contains_cycle(example2, 3));
    printf("%d ", contains_cycle(example3, 3));
}
```

I'm certain that there can be a faster way but the one above does work with your examples